# Loop not working corretly

Tags: excel, vba

My b and c columns are formatted as a Date and Time in each cell
and when i run this code:

```
Dim b As Range
Dim c As Range
For Each b In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("B").Cells
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("C").Cells
        If b.Value = c.Value Then
            c.Value = Null
        End If
    Next c
Next b
```

It will only make null values where the time is not equal.
Also it creates a bunch of blank rows in my spreadsheet.

Any ideas why?

Comment: I think, this is not what you want, try to use "For Each ... In a.Rows ... Next". In other words, try to loop through the rows!

Comment: The loop is probably working correctly, just not as intended.

Comment: You're only describing what the loop is doing...which is obvious from the code. Could you please describe what you *want* it to do. Perhaps you could include a screen shot of the data with some description of what you are tying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If your using UsedRange, 'Columns("B") will return the second column of that selection, not necesarily the Column B. I would suggest looking what gets selected with this:

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("B").Cells.Select`

So you can visually see what is being selected. It's probably not what you're thinking.

Comment: how do i just return what has values in the cells?

Comment: ok i fixed it by deleting unneccessary rows in the current spreadsheet.  How do I now stop it from deleting days that are a day apart? It deletes the days that are the same as well as a day apart.  The time stamp doesnt matter since its all 12:00:00

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to compare the values on the same row? Because your current code will delete anything in column c which is also found in column b.

Comment: yes same one but the ones that delete are either the same or a day off

Comment: change the format of the cells to general, you should see some numbers there instead of the dates. That is what is being compared.